# What is a mining round?

Tags: gpu-mining, hashrate

I was reading Claymore's GPU miner [thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=638915.0) and saw this, "current developer fee is 2.5%, miner mines 39 rounds for you and 1 round for developer."

What is a mining round?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this refers to hashes - it does 39 hashes for you and 1 hash for the developer, regardless of whether the hashes are valid or not. As Claymore is closed source, we can't easily verify this, but from what I have seen running the miner it seems like the most likely explanation.

Comment: How would it detect then?

Comment: @UsernameVF detect what? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: How does it detect how many hashes were done? Also, if its 39 hashes then 1 hash for dev and my hashrate is 100 h/s wouldn't it switch between pools way too often?

Comment: It doesn't switch pools, from what I have seen it uses the same pool that you are connecting to, but uses the developer's address instead of yours, and just sends 1 hash in 40 to that pool with his address (if it is a valid share, of course). The miner maintains 2 connections to the pool for this purpose. I'm not sure what you mean about the number of hashes.

Comment: Never mind, I somewhat understand now.

Comment: You can easily see it by dumping network traffic. The communication with the pool is cleartext JSON. I doubt it's per hash, as the overhead would be masive. It's probably by share, or by unit of time. In any case, it's an internal concept to that miner, rather than a Monero concept.